# how to do a exclusive (not including) join?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

prerequisites: neo4j-2.0.0 with the movie database (:play movies)

I'm James Thompson and i want to know which movies have been reviewed by person(s) which reviewed 'Cloud Atlas'. And the result shouldn't contain movies which i've already reviewed.

Here my iterative ongoing:

```
match (me:Person{name:"James Thompson"})-[:REVIEWED]->(ownmovies) return ownmovies
```

=> The Da Vinci Code, The Replacements

```
match (movies)<-[:REVIEWED]-(p:Person)-[:REVIEWED]->(movie:Movie{title:"Cloud Atlas"}) return movies
```

=> The Da Vinci Code, The Birdcage, Unforgiven, The Replacements

and now my rdbms damaged brain want to

```
match (me:Person{name:"James Thompson"})-[:REVIEWED]->(ownmovies),
(movies)<-[:REVIEWED]-(p:Person)-[:REVIEWED]->(movie:Movie{title:"Cloud Atlas"})
where ownmovies.title<>movies.title
return movies
```

=> The Da Vinci Code, The Birdcage, The Birdcage, Unforgiven, Unforgiven, The Replacements

but the documentation already outline, that *where* in graph isn't *where* in rdbms.

So how to write the combined query which results only The Birdcage and Unforgiven?

I've already experiment with "WITH", but now way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in your `WHERE` clause is that for each node bound in `movies` it does the test (`<>`) with each node bound in `ownmovies`. Since each `movies` has a different title than at least one `ownmovies` you get the all back. Since some `movies` have a different title than more than one `ownmovies` you get some of them back more than once. Since what you want to exclude the movies you have already reviewed, you can filter on that as a pattern instead of comparing values. You have to first bind 'yourself' in the `MATCH` clause, then bind all the movies that share a reviewer with "Cloud Atlas", and then in the `WHERE` clause you just exclude the movies that have a `REVIEWED` relationship to you, like so:

```
MATCH (me:Person{name:"James Thompson"}), (movies)<-[:REVIEWED]-(p:Person)-[:REVIEWED]->(movie:Movie{title:"Cloud Atlas"})
WHERE NOT (me)-[:REVIEWED]->(movies)
RETURN movies
```

Try experimenting with returning early, try `RETURN *`, `RETURN COUNT(*)`, `RETURN ownmovies, COUNT(movies)` and similar to get the hang of how patterns compound and how to avoid being haunted by Descartes and his products. Also, if you haven't already take a look at [from sql to cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/examples-from-sql-to-cypher.html) from the manual.